# PHP DirectoryIterator help

Tags: php, iterator, spl

In the following code, what can be called instead of `->getFilename()`?

```
<?php

foreach (new DirectoryIterator('../moodle') as $fileInfo) {
    if($fileInfo->isDot()) continue;
    echo $fileInfo->getFilename() . "<br>\n";
}

?>
```

PS, I have seen the documentation. Please [don't link to here](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php).

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

After posting this I realized that the Docs had the answer. My real question becomes, what do the other methods do? The Docs seem to be limited in regards to that.

Comment: 'What can be called instead of getFilename()' .... that depends on what you want to GET.

Comment: @Moshe.EDIT: Well if you want to be specific about which methods you dont understand tell us which ones. Ive found the Docs for the `SplFileInfo` related classes to be pretty self explanitory - if you have specific questions im sure myself or others can give you more detail but i dont think anyone here wants to rewrite documentation for the entire class(es) :-)

Comment: @prodigitalson - ok thanks. Will select your answer for now and ask again if I need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: 
Oops misread your code. What exactly are you after instead of the filename? youve seen the docs so you know there are methods for both the full path (`getPathname`) and just the path to the containing dir (`getPath`)... Im not sure what you want here...

I assume you want the directory name of `.` or `..` so to get that you could use `getPath` and then pop the last/second-to-last segment off or you could just use `dirname($fileInfo->getPathname())`

Comment: It is too bad that we so often have to assume... Another answer could be: "Any other method of the $fileInfo object could be called instead of getFilename()."

Comment: @Don, good point. I realized that after I posted the question.